# Boost::asio and tcp FIN bit

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, ftp, boost-asio

I write simple FTP server in boost asio. Now I started work with data channel of FTP protocol. And when I try to send data(by async_write_some), i need to have setted FIN bit in tcp packet. Otherwise i got situation when client waits for infinite.

1. How to send data with FIN bit?
2. May be boost sometimes automatically set FIN bit to packet(for example at closing) - so how to resolve this problem - as much as possible elegant way?

Comment: You send `FIN` by *closing* the connection. If you don't want to close the connection, I suggest you try to find out why the client blocks. If you want to explicitly set `FIN` on a packet, you have to use raw sockets, and basically reimplement large parts of the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: Ok, i already try to close socket, but FIN is not setted by socket.close(). I of course can to explore Filezilla code - but I want to do this in boost. Besides, client - is FireFox - so I think with client all ok :)

Comment: *How* do you know that `FIN` is not sent? Have you checked in e,g, Wireshark or similar tool? If you close a connection, then a `FIN` packet is sent as the first of [the four way connection termination handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination).

Comment: I check with Wireshark. Besides i did not call shutdown - may be think in this way?

Comment: Perhaps call shutdown :)